# Stacking columns horizontally on wider screens and vertically on smaller screens

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox

I'm trying to accomplish the following. I've dumbed it down for purposes of demonstration:

1. A page with a header, a footer, and 2 columns
2. The header is always on top (i.e., vertically above the rest of the content) with height 20px
3. The footer is always at the bottom (i.e., vertically below the rest of the content) with height 20px.
4. In between, there are 2 columns
5. If the viewport is wide enough, the 2 columns are presented side by side, and everything fits inside the viewport. Column A takes 75%, Column B 25%. Each is (100% - 40px) tall
6. If the viewport is not wide enough, the 2 columns are presented on top of each other, each 100% wide. Column A is still (100%-40px) tall, column B has a height to fit its content. The page is now more than 1 viewport tall (with the header visible when scrolling all the way up, and the footer visible when scrolling all the way down)
7. If content does not fit a column, a scroll bar should appear *inside* the overflowing column

I've accomplished all points except number 6 [here](https://jsfiddle.net/498xpp6n/1/)

I cannot got number 6 to work. I've tried `min-width`. I've also tried to 'port' the whole thing to bootstrap (I'm using bootstrap elements on the page already) but that doesn't work nicely with some angular components (that need to poll their parent's size; for some reason the element then keeps growing)

I'd be grateful for good ideas!

**edit**
I've tried using flexboxes. It's closer, but the viewport doesn't scroll when it gets too narrow... ideas? https://jsfiddle.net/498xpp6n/2/

**edit**
I've thought about it some more, and made a little change to the wanted column heights when going into stacked mode. Hope that doesn't ruin someone's day

Comment: What do you mean by wide enough?

Comment: Wide enough means, wider than a certain width specified in css, or e.g. at least as wide as the sum of the 2 min-width values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The layout is possible with flexbox. This is all you need:

**HTML**

```
<div id="outer-flex-container"><!-- primary flex container -->

    <div id="header">The Header The Header The Header ... </div><!-- flex item #1 -->

    <div id="inner-flex-container"><!-- flex item #2 -->

        <div id="mainpanel">Mainpanel Mainpanel Mainpanel Mainpanel Mainpanel ... </div>

        <div id="aside">settings settings settings settings settings settings ... </div>

    </div><!-- end #inner-flex-container -->

    <div id="footer">The Footer The Footer The Footer ... </div><!-- flex item #3 -->

</div><!-- end #outer-flex-container -->
```

**CSS**

```
html { height: 100%; }

body { height: 100%; margin: 0; }

#outer-flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
}

#inner-flex-container {
    display: flex;
    height: calc(100% - 40px);
}

#header { height: 20px; }

#footer { height: 20px; }

#mainpanel { flex: 0 0 75%; }

#aside { flex: 1; overflow-y: scroll; }

@media screen and ( max-width: 500px) { #inner-flex-container { flex-direction: column; } }
```

I believe the code above covers all seven points in your question :-)

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/498xpp6n/3/)

---

**UPDATE** (based on comments)

**HTML**

```
<div id="outer-flex-container"><!-- primary flex container -->

    <div id="header">The Header The Header The Header ... </div><!-- flex item #1 -->

    <div id="inner-flex-container"><!-- flex item #2 -->

        <div id="mainpanel">Mainpanel Mainpanel Mainpanel Mainpanel Mainpanel ... </div>

        <div id="aside">settings settings settings settings settings settings ... </div>

        <div id="footer">The Footer The Footer The Footer ... </div>

    </div><!-- end #inner-flex-container -->

</div><!-- end #outer-flex-container -->
```

Notes:

- moved footer into `.inner-flex-container`
- now only two primary flex items
- three inner flex items

**CSS**

```
body {  margin: 0; }

#outer-flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;     
}

#inner-flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#header { height: 20px; }

#mainpanel {
    flex: 0 0 75%;
    height: calc(100vh - 40px);
    min-height: calc(100vh - 40px);
    overflow-y: auto; 
}

#aside {
    flex: 0 0 25%;
    height: calc(100vh - 40px);
    overflow-y: auto;
}

#footer {
    flex-basis: 100%;
    height: 20px;
}

@media screen and ( max-width: 500px) {
    #inner-flex-container  { flex-direction: column; }
    #mainpanel { height: 100vh; }
    #aside { height: auto;  }
}
```

Notes:

- removed fixed heights (was limiting footer positioning on smaller screens)
- added footer to inner flex container so it's always below content columns

[**Revised Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/498xpp6n/8/)

Comment: Thanks Michael for your answer. It doesn't quite do what I want just yet - the column heights change when it goes into 'stacked mode' (which they should not), and the footer should be pushed down as well (i've edited rule 2 and 3 to be more clear)

Comment: In order to avoid scrollbar-in-scrollbar, I've also relaxed the height restriction on column B when going into stacked mode. It's more of an additional requirement (than a change in the requirements) so I hope it doesn't mess up your answer by too much

Comment: Thanks Michael! I updated it with an additional `min-height` for `#mainpanel` so that it has the same height in both situations (number 6), and now it seems to work exactly as wanted.